# content dissappears at screen width 659px

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I maintain the media queries that control the background to remain responsive and fit the browser edge to edge while not losing `.content` & img in `#flexiselDemo3` at width 659px where `.content` and img's in `#flexiselDemo3` disappear?

https://codepen.io/fjenpen/pen/pROPov

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    text decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 658px) {
    .bg {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        background-image: url("http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/repairing-lawn-    mower-engine-picture-id500782948");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        text decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: arial;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 659px) {
    .bg {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url("http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/repairing-lawn-    mower-engine-picture-id500782948");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        text-align: center;
        text decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: arial;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your issue is that you're giving `.bg` a display of `inline-block`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 658px) {
    .bg {
        ...
        display: inline-block; <- get rid of this
        ...
```

Comment: When I remove the inline-block space appears between .bg and .top. How can I maintain the background image being edge to edge without inline-block?

Comment: Just add some top padding to .bg: padding: 10px 0 0 0;